# how should i get color and compare them in android studio?

Tags: java, android, colors, textview, compare

**In Drawable folder I have white.xml**

.......

**In mainactivity.xml i have textview**

````
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:background="@drawable/white" />```
//secound textview same as above
**In mainActivity i want to get background Color and to compare them but its not working**

  ```  public void getColor(View view) {

        Drawable color1 = findViewById(R.id.text1).getBackground();
        Drawable color2 = findViewById(R.id.text2).getBackground();
           if(color1 == color2)
                   enter code here
                   //its also not working with .equal function
    }```
// how should i compare background color
````

Comment: white.xml code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>

            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#131313"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

Comment: can you explain properly what problem exactly you are facing?

Comment: I want to get background colour of textview and than to compare that both have same colour or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using direct color code for the background that only have a singular color like this:

```
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textviewWithColor"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#000000" <!--A direct color code instead of a drawable-->
      android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

You will able to obtain the color code in integer by:

```
  ColorDrawable background = (ColorDrawable) textviewWithColor.getBackground();
  int colorCode = background.getColor();
```

In your case,you could do:

```
int color1 = (ColorDrawable) findViewById(R.id.text1).getBackground().getColor();
int color2= (ColorDrawable) findViewById(R.id.text2).getBackground().getColor();

if(color1 == color2){
   //The color matches, do something
}
```

Comment: .getColor() function is not available

Comment: You have to cast it to (ColorDrawable) in order to use it

Comment: the error is shown as Cannot resolve method 'getColor' in 'Drawable'

Comment: There is no getColor in a Drawable, you have to use ColorDrawable, also the solution will only works if you are using a color directly as the background instead of using a "@drawable/white"